# adding jquery fade function to my background rotation script

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me wrap a fade in function around this, when ever I try put one in I screw up the script for some reason, i'm trying to get the new image to fade in rather than just replace the old one, or a quick fade out fade in, can anyone give me any pointers? Thanks

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function carousel_bg(id) {
            var bgimgs = [ 'banner-two.jpg', 'banner-three.jpg', 'banner-four.jpg' ]; // add images here..
            var img = bgimgs[id];
            var cnt = 3; // change this number when adding images..

            $('#main_banner').css("background-image", "url(img/"+img+")");
            id = id + 1;
            if (id==cnt) id = 0;

            setTimeout("carousel_bg("+id+")", 1000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
            carousel_bg(0);     
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var bgimgs = [ 'banner-two.jpg', 'banner-three.jpg', 'banner-four.jpg' ];
var cnt = bgimgs.length;
var id = 0;

function carousel_bg() {          
  var img_link = bgimgs[id];
  $('#main_banner').css("background-image","url('"+img_link+"')").fadeIn('slow');
  id = id + 1;
  if (id == cnt) id = 0;
 }

$(document).ready(function() {
  carousel_bg();

  setInterval(function(){
     $('#main_banner').fadeOut('slow',function(){
         carousel_bg();
     });
  }, 1000);
});
```

fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/AaRgR/1/

Comment: There is no fading function, seems like the same code as the one in the question but coded slightly differently.

Comment: opsssss my bad.. copy paste error.. thanks dude for poining this out.

Comment: I slightly changed your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/AaRgR/. You have to remove the arguments when you call carousel_bg() since id is a global variable in your script. Still, I think your solution is not what the question author expects, but let's see..

Comment: yeah thats a nice change.. thanks for the fiddle, i thought to create a fiddle but i didnt have image links... putting your fiddle in answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a fading effect, you need two `<div>` elements:

```
<div id="main_banner">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Using CSS, change the style of the inner divs so that they're one over the other and make the `.div2` appear over `.div1`:

```
#main_banner
{
    position:relative;
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
}

#main_banner > div
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
}

.div1
{
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Then, your script should be aware of it so you have to change it to something like this:

```
var activeId = 0;

function carousel_bg(id) {
    var bgimgs = [ 'banner-two.jpg', 'banner-three.jpg', 'banner-four.jpg' ]; // add images here..

    $('.div1').css("background-image", "url(img/"+bgimgs[activeId]+")");
    $('.div2').hide().css("background-image", "url(img/"+bgimgs[id]+")").fadeIn();

    activeId = id;

    id = (id + 1) % bgimgs.length; // 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ...

    setTimeout("carousel_bg("+id+")", 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
        carousel_bg(0);     
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NXHqq/)